# Why is the $s_1$ & $s_2$ between 0 and 1 in this proof?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am trying to understand why $0\leq s_1\leq 1$ and $0\leq s_2\leq 1$ in this proof for theorem 10. I understand everything else.

**Theorem**: [image: Theorem 10]

**Proof**: [image: Theorem 10 proof]

Thank you.

Comment: Does your book provide a definition for the parallelogram determined by two vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$?  If not, you may take $\{s_1 v_1 + s_2 v_2 : 0 \le s_1, s_2 \le 1\}$ as a definition.

Comment: Pleas do not use images to convey information not otherwise present in your post. [See here for the reasons why.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$b_1$ and $b_2$ determine a parallelogram (ie, they form the boundary around the edge of our parallelogram). $S$ is meant to be the set of points inside that boundary. Thus $s_1$ and $s_2$ act as scalars. By scaling them between 0 and 1 and taking the linear combination, we span the entire area inside the parallelogram.